# canvas fabric image , store as object and zip them up

Tags: php, canvas, fabricjs

```
<?php

class Mail{
  private $image_box;

  public $count = 0;
  public $zipper;

  $encoding = "base64";
  $type = "image/png";

  public function __construct(){
    $this->turnToImage();
  }

  public function addToObject($object_name, $object_data){
    //save to object 
    // $object_name : $object_data
  }

  public function turnToImage(){
    $this->image_box = $_POST['canvas_data'];

    foreach($this->image_box as $img)
    {
    $this->count++;
    $data = substr($img, strpos($img, ","));
    $image_name ="OrderImg".$this->count.".png";
    $this->addToObject($image_name, $data);
    }

  }

  public function toZip(){

  }

}

$Mail = new Mail();
?>
```

i have canvas fabric image data , and i want to decode to image and zip it up and send by mail.

so 1st question is how do i save the my data to object and be like this ?

```
object{
$object_name1 : object_data1,
$object_name2 : object_data2
}
```

2nd how do i zip them up ? after i store to object and some how zip them up together as one zip file ? i am stucked here.